[GMSx_SRLRegistry internalService:scopeTags:]: No binding was found for required, single-bound service: GMSAnalyticsLogging_API
I create a iOS framework project which use GoogleMaps iOS SDK (version: 8.4.0, include from CocoaPods) and aggregate it as XCFramework Lib.
And Other iOS App project try to include My XCFramework Lib and open a ViewController with GMSMapView from the Lib.
The overall structure is as follows:
(I don't have enough reputation to post images)
https://xattacker.github.io/framework_with_gmap.jpg
But the MapView did not show any map content. (API key already set)
And Debug console always show:
[GMSx_SRLRegistry internalService:scopeTags:]: No binding was found for required, single-bound service: GMSAnalyticsLogging_API
Can anyone please tell me what steps are wrong?
Environment:
IDE: XCode 16.0
XCFramework Project Swift version: 5.0
GoogleMaps iOS SDK: v 8.4.0 / v 9.1.0 (the same situation, include from CocoaPods: v 1.15.2)
running iOS: 18.0 (iPhone 16 Simulator) / 17.7 (iPhone 15)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Sorry, I revised the question content

I finally found a solution by myself
reference follow:
Class is implemented in both, One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined
We should removed the duplicated flag "GoogleMaps" (and other related flags)  of OTHER_LDFLAGS in Pods-[YourAppProject_Which_include_Framework].debug.xcconfig
